# in query for search data from database

Tags: php, sql

get current address from google and  i want to search data from database through  **T Extension, Nanhey Park, Om Vihar, Uttam Nagar, Delhi, 110059, India** but m getting error

```
SELECT *
FROM `thyrocare_location`
WHERE `location` IN (T Extension, Nanhey Park, Om Vihar, Uttam Nagar, Delhi, 110059, India)
```

Comment: You probably just need single quotes around the string constants.  I vote to close this type of question as a simple typographic error.

Comment: i know its single quotes around error but point is that i have save location as cookies and m trying to replace quotes so not getting any changes

Answer (score 0):

for string values in a IN clause you need  quote around each values

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `thyrocare_location`
    WHERE `location` IN ('T Extension', 'Nanhey Park', 
                    'Om Vihar', 'Uttam Nagar', 'Delhi', '110059', 'India')
```

or if the content of your IN clause  is just one string  then you can use this way

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `thyrocare_location`
    WHERE `location` =  ('T Extension, Nanhey Park, 
                    Om Vihar, Uttam Nagar, Delhi, 110059, India')
```

Comment: m trying to replace , to ','  in this formate but i cant